# Is there a way I can save "views" that comprise hidden / shown columns and specific filters turned on?

Tags: google-sheets

For instance when I'm working in a large spreadsheet with many columns I like to hide specific columns to allow me to present or focus in on a set of data, this often means hiding columns eg. C:C, F:H, P:S, Z:AC. When I need to view everything again I manually turn the columns back on, but when I want to hide them again after I need to hide them all manually.

Is there a simple way to be able to save a "view" that will capture how my spreadsheet is currently using hidden rows, columns and filters and allow me to toggle it on / off as required?

Comment: That is not a built-in function. Use [tag:google-apps-script] or an add-on.

Answer (score 1):

No.

> That is not a built-in function. Use google-apps-script or an add-on. – Rubén Mar 6 at 11:34